# Calling a "local" function by string name without eval?

Tags: javascript, function, eval

Since eval is no longer used for several reasons, I'm dealing with some problems calling functions. So I'm making a "Function Caller" to replace eval. First of all: am I bringing back eval issuses like security, speed and debugging difficulties? Here is the testing code:

```
function globalFunc(p){
    console.log("Run globalFunc: "+p);
}
var globalVarFunc = function(p){
    console.log("Run globalVarFunc: "+p);
}
function ini(){
    var varFunc = function(p){
        console.log("Run varFunc: "+p);
    }
    //
    funcCaller(function(p){ console.log("Run anonymous function: "+p); }, "anonymous");
    funcCaller('function(p){ console.log("Run anonymous function: "+p); }', "anonymous");
    funcCaller(globalFunc, "global function");
    funcCaller("globalFunc", "global string");
    funcCaller(globalVarFunc, "globalVarFunc function");
    funcCaller("globalVarFunc", "globalVarFunc string");
    funcCaller(localFunc, "local function");
    funcCaller("localFunc", "local string");
    funcCaller(varFunc, "local var function");
    funcCaller("varFunc", "local var string");
    //
    function localFunc(p){
        console.log("Run localFunc: "+p);
    }
}
function funcCaller(func, p){
    if(typeof(func)=="string"){
        p += " as string";
        try { window[func](p); } catch(e) { 
            console.log("Catch window error trying "+p) ;
            try { this[func](p); } catch(e) { console.log("Catch this error trying "+p) }
        }
    } else if(typeof(func)=="function"){
        p += " as function";
        try { func(p); } catch(e) { console.log("Catch error trying "+p) }
    } else {
        console.log("Unknown situation: "+typeof(func)+" trying "+p);
    }
}
```

The log result by Safari 5.1:

```
Run anonymous function: anonymous as function
Catch window error trying anonymous as string
Catch this error trying anonymous as string
Run globalFunc: global function as function
Run globalFunc: global string as string
Run globalVarFunc: globalVarFunc function as function
Run globalVarFunc: globalVarFunc string as string
Run localFunc: local function as function
Catch window error trying local string as string
Catch this error trying local string as string
Run varFunc: local var function as function
Catch window error trying local var string as string
Catch this error trying local var string as string
```

Maybe to run an anonymous function as string is not advisable, same problem as eval. But why "varFunc" doesn't work if "globalVarFunc" does?

EDIT: I wish at list to run "varFunc".

Comment: What exactly is it that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Also, "varFunc" **did** work - it's right there in your debug output!

Comment: @Pointy - I think it's the literal `"varFunc"` the OP is asking about. In other words, the OP doesn't understand passing references and scope.

Comment: If you [really want & need `eval`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/197769/1048572), then you should use plain `eval`, instead of some crude workaround that tries to emulate it. However, there is almost always a better solution.

Comment: I wrote the main goal of the question above. @JaredFarish: you're right! Bergi: I think eval will be deprecated, will stop working at all.

Answer (score 1):

What I think you're missing are the relationship between two concepts:

- Pass by reference
- Scope

Let's take a simplified example:

```
function check(arg) {
    try {
        var func = new Function('return ' + arg + '()');

        console.log(typeof arg, this);
        console.log(func);
        console.log(func());
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

function run() {
    function test() {
        console.log('Local test() run.');
    }

    check(test);
    check('test');
}

var r = new run();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/7Lz15qou/

When `run()` is called, within it has it's own *scope*, which is local to itself. The variables and function declared within it have their own *references* that are only seen within `function run(){}`.

When you pass `run(test)`, you're passing the variable's value by looking up it's *reference*, which allows it to be understood as a copy; as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/bev8v17x/1/), you don't affect the originally-referenced variable, you change it's *local* instance*.

The reason why this is important is that, without the *value* associated with that reference in the new scope (a *function* value in your case), all you have is a string with no relation to it's original value. `eval()` or not, you can't call something which is simply `undefined` in that scope; it's illogical.

It's a bit like having two show rings and a magical cage with lions in one ring. When you send a `Lion` to the other ring, `ring(Lion)`, you've *pointed at the cage and said get a copy of the lion and put it in that ring*.

When you say `ring('Lion')`, you've told the other ring *Lion*, but there is no `Lion` defined. So that ring is running around saying *Lion! Lion!* but there's no `Lion`, only a word. `Lion` is `undefined`, so instead of getting a show, you get a comical, yet faulty result. People will probably want their money back.

This is why what you're trying to do won't work.

---

<sup>*** Many languages allow you to pass by reference, but Javascript does not.**</sup>

Comment: jsfiddle is down, I'll do more tests here, I wish to understand this concepts once for all!

Comment: While jsfiddle don't come back, I tested your mind blowing code. I understood that, in my code, globalFunc is already defined inside funcCaller because both are in the root. The lion jump inside the cage, and confused my mind. Going further, I think might be a difference between passing a string and a function to the caller: will be running outside or inside the cage? This might be outside the scope of the question, your call. The answer seams to be that sometimes a string won't work and is not a problem of code, but of scope. Thanks so far!

Comment: The answer is that a string has to reference something that *evaluates* as pointing to a function (the *cage* represents the box storing the function in memory, the reference is it's address) for it to call a function. In reality, the *cage* is copied with a lion *in it*. When you call a *global* function, you're really calling an implicit `window['functionName']()` (or `window.functionName()`). In other words, you're referencing an object property pointing to a function in memory that evaluates to that string. For another take, see: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/7Lz15qou/2/